# Cannot install package "predictionet" on Windows

Tags: windows, r, installation

I am trying to install [predictionet](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/predictionet.html) but having troubles. Clearly there are no windows binaries available so I have been trying to install by building from source.

I have Rtools installed from [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/).

So far I have tried to use this command:

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Blah/predictionet_1.10.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

But I am receiving this error message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Blah/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'predictionet' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="predictionet.dll" OBJECTS="foo_mrmr.o mrnet_adapted.o mrnet_adapted2.o mrnet_ensemble_standalone.o"' had status 309
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'predictionet'
* removing 'C:/Users/Blah/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/predictionet'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Blah\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/predictionet_1.10.0.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Blah/Desktop/predictionet_1.10.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am new to R so have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this, any help would be much obliged!

Note: I am using Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

You may try :

> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
>
> biocLite("predictionet")